# CROSS APPLY query with CASE and running totals

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply, running-totals

I'm trying to make this business logic make sense, but I'm not having any luck.
The rule is I can have a sale with discounts from percentage and value. But the value is to be subtracted after discounted percentage, from the sequence column.

If this was only about percentages, I could make it work, the problem is the case in the middle when in the same sale there's a value to subtract from Current value.

```
+--------+-----------+------+----+---+
| SaleId | Discount  | Type | S  | q |
+--------+-----------+------+----+---+
|      1 |      0.15 | P    | rc | 1 |
|      1 |     10.05 | V    | l  | 2 |
|      2 |      0.05 | P    | rc | 1 |
|      3 |      0.05 | P    | rc | 1 |
|      3 |      8.00 | V    | l  | 2 |
|      3 |      0.25 | P    | rc | 3 |
+--------+-----------+------+----+---+

+--------+--------+
| SaleId | Amount |
+--------+--------+
|      1 | 100.00 |
|      2 | 200.00 |
|      3 |  50.00 |
+--------+--------+


+--------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------+--------------+
| SaleId | Amount | Discount | Type | Seq | T_Disc | CurrentValue |
+--------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------+--------------+
|      1 |    100 |     0,15 | Perc |   1 |   0,85 |           85 |
|      1 |    100 |    10,05 | Val  |   2 |      0 |        74,95 |
|      2 |    200 |     0,05 | Perc |   1 |   0,95 |          190 |
|      3 |     50 |      0,1 | Perc |   1 |   0,95 |           45 |
|      3 |     50 |        8 | Val  |   2 |      0 |           37 |
|      3 |     50 |     0,25 | Perc |   3 |      0 |        27,75 |
+--------+--------+----------+------+-----+--------+--------------+
```

Sale 3:

- 50 minus 10%
- 45 minus 8
- 37 minus 25%

After this I need to display the last row from each `SaleId`.

Can you please advise if this is possible?

I'm trying CROSS APPLY and a CTE (WITH clause):

```
WITH CTE_CalcTotalDisc
AS 
(
    Select A.SaleId
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),B.Amount) Amount
    ,Discount
    ,Tipo
    ,A.Seq
    ,CASE WHEN Tipo='Val' THEN convert(decimal(8,3),Discount)
        ELSE convert(decimal(8,3),1-(1*Discount))END AS T_Disc
    ,CASE WHEN Tipo='Val' THEN convert(decimal(8,3),Amount-Discount)
          WHEN Tipo='Perc' THEN convert(decimal(8,3),Amount-(Amount*Discount))
        ELSE convert(decimal(8,3),0.00) --convert(decimal(6,5),1-(1*Discount))
        END 
    AS CurrentValue
    From #disc A, #Sales B
    where Seq=1 AND A.SaleId=B.SaleId

    UNION ALL

    Select d.SaleId
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),0.00) 
    ,d.Discount
    ,d.Tipo
    ,d.Seq
    --,convert(decimal(6,5),(1-(1*d.Discount))*T_Disc) T_Disc
    --,CASE WHEN d.Tipo='Val' THEN d.Discount ELSE convert(decimal(6,5),1-(1*d.Discount))END 
    , CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),0.000) AS T_Disc
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),0.000) AS CurrentValue
    From #disc d --, #Sales B
        JOIN CTE_CalcTotalDisc ad on d.SaleId=ad.SaleId
                            AND d.Seq=ad.Seq+1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_CalcTotalDisc I1
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT 
  --SUM(CurrentValue)   RunningTotal
  I1.CurrentValue-(I1.CurrentValue*I1.Discount)   RunningTotal
  FROM CTE_CalcTotalDisc I2
  WHERE I1.SALEID = I2.SALEID
  --AND I1.Tipo = I2.Tipo
  AND I1.Seq <= I2.Seq
)C
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Also, I tried formatting your tables, If I messed up at some point please redo it yourself.

Comment: Your query seems to suggest you are using SQL Server and I've tagged your question as such, but please specify the version of your SQL Server instance as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work on [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) 2012+. Note that there were a couple of inconsistencies between your supplied SQL and the sample schema that you provided and I think I have followed the names in your SQL.

```
With CTE_CalcTotalDisc As (
    Select d.SaleID, s.Amount, d.Discount, d.Tipo, d.Seq,
        T_Disc = iif(d.Tipo = 'V', d.Discount, (s.Amount * d.Discount)),
        CurrentValue = iif(d.Tipo = 'V', s.Amount - d.Discount, iif(d.Tipo = 'P', s.Amount - (s.Amount * d.Discount), 0))
      From #disc As d
      Join #sales As s On d.SaleID = s.SaleID
      Where d.Seq = 1
    Union All
    Select d.SaleID, Amount = cte.CurrentValue, d.Discount, d.Tipo, d.Seq,
        T_Disc = iif(d.Tipo = 'V', d.Discount, (cte.CurrentValue * d.Discount)),
        CurrentValue = iif(d.Tipo = 'V', cte.CurrentValue - d.Discount, iif(d.Tipo = 'P', cte.CurrentValue - (cte.CurrentValue * d.Discount), 0))
      From #disc As d
      Join CTE_CalcTotalDisc As cte
        On d.SaleID = cte.SaleID
        And d.Seq = cte.Seq + 1),
CTE_Ordered As (
    Select SaleID, CurrentValue, 
        Discount = Sum(T_Disc) Over (Partition By SaleID Order By Seq Asc), 
        RowNo = Row_Number() Over (Partition By SaleID Order By Seq Desc)
      From CTE_CalcTotalDisc)
--Select * From CTE_CalcTotalDisc
Select * From CTE_Ordered Where RowNo = 1;
```

Note the use of `Row_Number()`, partitioned by `SaleID` and sorted descending by `Seq` to get the final value, and the use of `Sum()` to get the running total of the discount.

You can uncomment the commented select statement to view all rows, not just the final row for each `SaleID`.